# Перевести число в unsigned long = 83e58955 в строку char[9] = "83e58955"

Tags: c, char

Всем привет. Требуется помощь с переводом unsigned long в char.
Пример:
Перевести

```
unsigned long out1 = 0x83e58955;
```

в строку

```
char out[9] = "83e58955".
```

Помогите с алгоритмом пожалуйста.

Comment: `sprintf(out, "%08x", in);` ?

Comment: Может, все же `unsigned long out = 0x83e58955;`?

Comment: Целый тип long имеет размер 8 байт (64 бита). Минимальное значение -9 223 372 036 854 775 808, максимальное значение 9 223 372 036 854 775 807. Где вы видите 16 бит? Куда такую экспоненту вы засунете? `Для сравнения — количество атомов в наблюдаемой Вселенной составляет по разным оценкам от 4⋅10^79 до 10^81`

Comment: @Harry да, именно так. и эту же цифру перевести в char, чтобы получилось в массиве "0x83e58955"

Comment: Цифру или число? Если цифру - то какую именно? Первую? А вообще вам уже ответили - `sprintf`...

Comment: @Harry, да, вижу что мне ответили выше. Этот способ мне помог.

Comment: @insolor спасибо!